# cron daemon not getting correct controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have almost successfully setup a Cron job on my server, but I cannot call the correct controller.

Job:

```
  */15 * * * * php fullpath/index.php cron
```

result: I get the HTML output of the default controller and not my Cron controller.

job:

```
  */15 * * * * php fullpath/index.php cron index
```

result: I get the HTML output of the default controller and not my Cron controller.

Can someone please advice what wrong i am doing?

NOTE: I don't want to use `wget` or `curl`

Comment: What you're doing wrong is assuming that `php index.php cron` as a shell script is in any way, shape or form equivalent to making an HTTP request to `/cron`. It's not.

Comment: try using wget and url to your controller/method........

Comment: Wget returns me the below error:                                   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-04-10 12:13:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: what is the url..........

Comment: http://www.example.mobi/index.php/cron/index

Comment: What is the version of CI you are using? Can you do a simple test with a separate controller as per http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html and see if that works - call from terminal before setting cronjob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create copy of your index.php, and name it cli.php.

At the beginning of cli.php add

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

/* we don't need to be limited by...normal limitations */
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

/* make sure this isn't being called by a web browser */
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) die('Permission denied.');

/* set some constants */
define('CMD', 1);

/* manually set the URI path based on command line arguments... */
unset($argv[0]); /* ...but not the first one */
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] =  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/' . implode('/', $argv) . '/';
```

Then change your cron to call cli.php instead of index.php.